# WCF DataContract: mapping JSON object to C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, python, json, wcf, dictionary

I would like to deserialize a JSON dictionary I receive from a python application via HTTP into a `Dictionary` in C#.

The JSON object looks like this:

```py
{
    "native_dict": {
        "foo": 0,
        "bar": 1
    },
    "obj_dict": [
        {"Key": "foo", "Value": 0},
        {"Key": "bar", "Value": 1},
    ]
}
```

It contains two attempts of passing the dictionary. The first would be the native JSON format and the second seemed to be the format C# needs.

Both will be converted to this XML format:

```xml
<root type="object">
  <value type="object">

    <native_dict type="object">
      <bar type="number">1</bar>
      <foo type="number">0</foo>
    </native_dict>

    <obj_dict type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <Value type="number">0</Value>
        <Key type="string">foo</Key>
      </item>
      <item type="object">
        <Value type="number">1</Value>
        <Key type="string">bar</Key>
      </item>
    </obj_dict>

  </value>
</root>
```

In my application I tried these DataContracts:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class MyDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "native_dict")]
    private Dictionary<string, int> MyDict1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "obj_dict")]
    private MyDictionary<string, int> MyDict1 { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract
    (Name = "obj_dict",
    ItemName = "item"
    KeyName = "Key", 
    ValueName = "Value")]
public class MyDictionary: Dictionary<string, int> { }
```

None of them can be resolved.

Is there a way to define a `DataContract` that the Serializer can use to convert the JSON object to a `Dictionary`, without rewriting the Serializer?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use List instead of Dictionary for your case. You create a property with type List where objectItem is a class having key and value as own properties. WCF datacontract will deserialize the incoming json string into c# list object.

Comment: Unfortunately using a List is not what I want to do. The Dictionary would make my Interface a lot easier to use for the users.